# How we use an application server like Passenger with a less common web server (like Caddy)?

Tags: webserver, passenger, caddy

We're currently using passenger as our ruby application server, and using the Apache plugin for passenger. There are only plugins for NGINX and Apache with Passenger but we are thinking of using Caddy as our web-server.

Is there any way to integrate these two tools, or more generally, for other application servers how can you integrate Caddy with them?

I found [this](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/wiki/Extending-Caddy) on extending caddy but that seems more like features, whereas with an application server I don't even know where to start. Or if it's different from any other extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Passenger in its Standalone mode and then setup a reverse proxy from Caddy. [Here is a guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html) on how to setup Apache/Nginx to reverse proxy to Passenger Standalone, but the principle can be applied to Caddy too.

Comment: Are you planning to implement a module for caddy? Better question: is there even a possibility to do this?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible. Are we going to do it? I can only say "yes" for certain when Caddy becomes much more popular than it is right now. Having said that, Caddy has some interesting features that we may want to imitate in the future, but on top of Nginx.

Comment: @Hongli, it looks like it's more popular now :) I've been using OpenResty with 
lua-resty-auto-ssl but the latter is dead. Caddy seems to do this auto SSL stuff already. Is reverse proxy still the recommended way to go with Caddy?